# Python noughts and crosses game

Tags: python

I need help in allowing this function to stop people overriding co-ordinates another player has already entered in their game of noughts and crosses

```
def CheckValidMove(XCoordinate, YCoordinate, Board):

    ValidMove = True 
    '''This function makes sure the coordinate inputed
    by the user is valid, e.g. from 1 - 3 displayed on the board'''
    if (XCoordinate < 1) or (XCoordinate > 3): 
        ValidMove = False
    if (YCoordinate < 1) or (YCoordinate > 3): 
        ValidMove = False 
    return ValidMove
```

Comment: Please expend on your question. What is your problem ? Where do you need help exactly ? Show more code.

Comment: ok so the users input coordinates in the grid for the noughts an crosses game, however when a player enters a nought or cross in one place, the other player can overide it, thats what im confused on how to fix

Comment: @user1655562 Then, you should add a check whether or not the position entered is already occupied or not. I don't see the problem, can you explain it to me?

Comment: Ok, it checks if both co-ordinates inputted are correct values e.i. they are placed on the table, what i can't figure out how to fix is when one player makes a move, the other player can overide it with their piece e.g. X or O, this isn't the main body of the code its just a seperate function

Comment: But i have no idea what to put in to stop that happening

Comment: How would you do it in a real game?

Comment: not let the person draw on your spot ? :L

Comment: Good. Now how do you determine which spot is "yours"? You check the `Board` to see if that spot has your mark on it. Does your `Board` object have that capability? Some kind of `Board.getMark(XCoordinate, YCoordinate)` function?

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep track of the *state* of each position on your grid. If a player selects a position, mark that position as occupied.

You could use a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to achieve this, for example:

```
board = dict()
board[(x,y)] = "occupied"
```

then you can easily find out if it's occupied:

```
if board[(x,y)] == "occupied":
    print " this move is unfortunately not available! "
```

Comment: Ok, i tried that but i get this traceback error, any ideas why - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//4051apps001/academy-students$/Academy-Intake-07/matthew.wilson07/Documents/2010_Comp1_Code.py", line 111, in <module>
    ValidMove = CheckValidMove(XCoord, YCoord, Board)
  File "//4051apps001/academy-students$/Academy-Intake-07/matthew.wilson07/Documents/2010_Comp1_Code.py", line 59, in CheckValidMove
    if Board[(XCoord,YCoord)] == "Occupied":
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Comment: You should learn to interpret the error tracebacks. These tend to contain helpful information for debugging purposes. This one tells you, _that list you gave me can't be indexed using a tuple._ Note that a `dict()` _can_ be indexed using a tuple.

Comment: English? I have no idea what i have to do please can someone give me a straight answer?

Comment: @user1655562 you need to ask a straight question, in order to get a straight answer. Plainly provide all information about the context of your function, how is it used, what are the objects, what is the intended behavior, how does it differ from the observed behavior, what have you tried to solve the problem on your own (e.g., what relevant pages have you found in the documentation and what information is still unclear to you)?